# How many rows can be displayed on one page in rdl

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I Created a rdl report .Its working fine but i can not scroll to the end.I mean if there are 10000 records it will show me only 2000 records and other records are not visible .I try page break but its not working.

[image]

[image]

As you can see i scroll it to end but all the records are not visible.Please help me how i can fix this problem

Comment: Is there a reason for hiding the toolbar (from our eyes)?

Comment: no special reasoni just crop it

Comment: Inhide the toolbar and confirm that you are on the last page. If so, check if the total row is hidden.